# macro only runs manually

Tags: excel, vba

My knowledge with VBA is fairly basic so this may seem like a silly question.

I have written a code so that cell A1 in sheet1 will read "XX" if cell B1 in sheet2 has a value in it. The code works but only if I select it and run it manually from VBA. if cell B1 in sheet2 has a value in it, cell A1 in sheet1 is not updating automatically. Here is the code

```
Sub IsNumeric()
If Sheets ("Sheet2").Range("B2) > 0 Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "XX"
End If
End Sub
```

Cell B2 in sheet2 is a formula which will only generate a number if another cell is selected. i am not sure if this is relevant but as i mentioned the code is working just fine, just not automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use an `IF` formula, in Sheet1 A1?  You could look at using Sheet2's change events also

Comment: Also, IsNumeric exists as a function in VBA, so may be best to use a different name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code a touch.  Have a proper UDF defined and called from Sheet1 A1, with a reference passed to Sheet2 A1, for example

The function

```
Function IsNumeric2(rngCheck As Excel.Range)

If rngCheck.Value > 0 Then
    IsNumeric2 = "XX"
Else
    IsNumeric2 = ""
End If

End Function
```

The call, in cell A1, `=IsNumeric2(Sheet2!A1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want macro's to work automatically, based on an event in the workbook, you can add a workbook event macro in ThisWorkbook. In this case you can use the Workbook_SheetChange event for instance, which runs everytime you make a change on a sheet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object,ByVal Source As Range) 
 Application.EnableEvents = False 'Switch off events because otherwise it gets triggered again for the changes made in this macro
 'First make sure that it only triggers when you change B2 of sheet 2
 If Source.Address = "$B$2" and Source.Parent.Name = "Sheet2" then
     If Source.Value > 0 Then
         ThisWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "XX"
     End If
 end if
 Application.EnableEvents = True 'Turn the events back on again.
End Sub
```